# Browser support for "e.target.files"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing web app targeted mainly to chrome (desktop & Android Tablet) + to few mobile browsers on non-Android Tablets.

I have an html file upload field on my page,

```
input type="file" id="fileId"
```

OnChange event of this field I'm getting the attached file path (C:\fakepath\fileName.jpg).

The problem is I want only the file name not the full path, so if I use `e.target.files` to get file name will it be supported on all major mobile browsers?

P.S. On chrome desktop & Android tablet it is supported. And i use jquery-1.9.1 with backbone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find support tables for HTML and CSS features here

http://caniuse.com/#search=file

Though the best way to sniff for features on the fly is to use a feature detection library like modernizr

http://modernizr.com